# Meet an error when I use cassandra cql to load Yahoo financial csv formated data

Tags: csv, import, cassandra, cql, datastax

I want to import Yahoo financial csv formated data using Cassandra cql. Part of the data file:

```
    Date           Open        High         Low        Close    Volume  Adj Close
   1/15/2016    130.009995  130.880005  128.869995  130.029999  8895400 130.029999
   1/14/2016    131.929993  133.789993  131.220001  132.910004  5703100 132.910004
   1/13/2016    133.5   134.279999  131.100006  131.169998  4672300 131.169998
   1/12/2016    133.649994  133.779999  131.130005  132.899994  5073700 132.899994
   1/11/2016    131.809998  133.820007  131.759995  133.229996  4967000 133.229996
```

Here is the schema I define:

```
    create table HisPrice (
    Date text primary key,
    Open float,
    High float,
    Low float,
    Close float,
    Volume int, 
    AdjClose float
    );
```

When I use this schema and use the Copy command ***COPY HisPrice (Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, AdjClose) from '\filename.csv'***, I got the following error:

**no viable alternative at input ',' (..., adjclose) values ('Date',[Open],...)"**

If I define all the data types as **text**, e.g (Low text), there will be no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the error message, I think you could try removing the header of the CSV.

With **Cassandra 3.2**, there is also an option to skip first N rows: SKIPROWS.

Read this: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-features-in-cqlsh-copy

Comment: @ doanduyhai  Thank you, it works. I though Cassandra could automatically skip the header...